# Error: Parsing Author in Json

Tags: android

I had a project, but, it seems that I have missed it. The problem is about parsing Author in Json, Author is not always present. So, how to parse a missing field that might be present or not.

The error code that my reviewer has provided. I don't understand what he means and what I should do to fix it.

See on the picture, please click on the link to see the picture.

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srm4x.png)

**This is the code:**

```
    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding news to
    List <NewsFeed> newsfeeds = new ArrayList <>();

    // parse the JSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
    // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
    // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.

    try {

        // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject( newsfeedJSON );

        // For a given news, extract the JSONObject associated with the
        // key called "response",
        JSONObject response = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject( "response" );
        // Extract the JSONArray with the key called "result",
        // which represents a list of results (or news).
        JSONArray newsfeedArray = response.getJSONArray( "results" );

        //in the newsfeedArray, I create an {@link news} object
        for (int i = 0; i < newsfeedArray.length(); i++) {

            // Get a single news at position i within the list of news
            JSONObject currentNewsFeed = newsfeedArray.getJSONObject( i );


            // Extract the value for the key called "type"
            String id = currentNewsFeed.getString( "sectionId" );

            // Extract the value for the key called "name"
            String name = currentNewsFeed.getString( "sectionName" );


            // Extract the value for the key called "title"
            String title = currentNewsFeed.getString( "webTitle" );
            if (title.contains( "|" )) {
                String[] arrayString = title.split( "\\|" );
                title = arrayString[0].trim(); //
            }

            // Extract the value for the key called "date"
            String date = currentNewsFeed.getString( "webPublicationDate" );

            // Extract the value for the key called "url"
            String url = currentNewsFeed.getString( "webUrl" );

            // Extract the value for the key called author tied to webtitle
            JSONObject fields = currentNewsFeed.getJSONObject( "fields" );
            JSONArray tags = currentNewsFeed.getJSONArray( "tags" );
            JSONObject tagsObject = tags.getJSONObject( 0 );
            String author;
            if (fields.has( "byline" ) && (tags.length() != 0)) {
               author = tagsObject.getString( "byline" );
            } else author = "No Author";


            //{@link news} object with the type, name, title, time,
            // and url from the JSON response.
            NewsFeed newsfeed = new NewsFeed( id, name, title, date, url, author);

            // Add the new {@link News Feed} to the list of news feeds.
            newsfeeds.add( newsfeed );
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
        // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
        // with the message from the exception.
        Log.e( "QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news feed JSON results", e );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the tags array you are directly accessing the data inside the array like this, this is causing an exception.

```
JSONArray tags = currentNewsFeed.getJSONArray( "tags" );
JSONObject tagsObject = tags.getJSONObject( 0 );
```

change that to this

```
String author;
      JSONArray tags = currentNewsFeed.getJSONArray( "tags" );
      if(tags != null && tags.length() > 0 ) {
          JSONObject tagsObject = tags.getJSONObject( 0 );
          if (fields.has( "byline" ) && (tags.length() != 0)) {
               author = tagsObject.getString( "byline" );
           }
      }else author = "No Author";
```

doing so you will only access your tags array when at least one item is there, else your author will be "no author".

Comment: Even simpler would be `tagsObject.optString("byline", "No Author");` Then you can forget about the `if..else`block containing `if (fields.has( "byline" )...`

Comment: It provides a fallback value..even if the `key` doesn't exist. It can come in handy at times when you have no control over the API.

Comment: yup read about it, been a long time since I actually parsed json manually, mostly i rely on Gson.

Comment: Hi war_Hero, the App fetch the data, but, when I click on it to open the webpage of the news, the App crashes.

Comment: There is no more Error. But the App is no longer clickable on the phone

Comment: then there is some other issue, have you added a click listener and set an click event on button.

Comment: I should I put the url at the last position!!! that is why the app wasn't clickable.

Comment: ok, glad i could help please accept the answer so that it will help others with similar problem.

Comment: this code is Awesome! author = tagsObject.optString( "webtitle", "No Author" );